# too much data for RSA block, only when using CipherOutputSream

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, outputstream

I am currently trying to encrypt some string using Java JDK version is 1.8.0.  The process is like this:

> RSA-PrivateKey(MD5Hash(original-string))

I am using Cipher and BC for encrypting & adding padding. Since I would like to output the Cipher instance, and re-generate it in another class. So I use CipherOutputStream to output the encrypted String as well as the cipher instance.
The code is going well before I specify the following code.

```
public void outputCipherFile() throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos,cipher);

    //this.encryptedString is the String I wish to encrypt, which datatype is byte[]
    cos.write(this.encryptedString);
    cos.close();

}
```

If I remove the method call to outputCipherFile(), the encryption works. But when I doing the above code statement, the follow errors occur:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1832)
    at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:158)
    at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:144)
    at com.domain.JavaEncryptionProject.outputCipherFile(JavaEncryptionProject.java:132)<5 internal calls>
```

I found some reference online about RSA is too short for encrypting string. But I am not quite understand why it works in encryption and decryption, fail in output the txt with CipherOutputStram. Please help.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Read about the differences of private-public key ciphers (e.g. RSA) and block ciphers (e.g. AES).

Comment: Personally, I think that the error makes quite literal sense. You're trying to encrypt too much data. RSA can only encrypt as many bytes as it's key is long, minus a few for padding normally.

Comment: But when I do Cipher.dofinal(this.originalString) with the same set of RSA key, it's okay. The string can be decrypted and encrypted.

Comment: Be warned: Encryption of a hash value is ***not*** signature generation; your code makes no sense. I can see a call to MD5 on top, and then no such call in your streaming code, maybe that can explain the difference?